# Event handler (button > onclick) function code execution lasts for a moment only

Tags: javascript, button, event-handling

It is a dummy banking project. The following addEventListener function is used to check if the login password matches with existing array. If yes, then corresponding account details are displayed.

The problem is that when login details are entered correct, the correct information is shown on the screen for one second and then the screen is set to the previous state.

I think there is some problem with the login button. Hence I commented all the code in the callback function and tried logging simple string to console.log(). Even there it appears for a second and then vanishes. In fact, the code execution stays in effect only for a moment once the button is pressed.

**The code:**

```
const loginUser = function(){

 let inputLogin = inputLoginUsername.value;
 let inputPswd = inputLoginPin.value;

 for(let [index,[userId,passWord]] of identifyUser.entries()){
   if(userId === inputLogin && passWord == inputPswd){
      displayMovements(accounts[index].movements);
      break;
   }else { 
      continue;
    }
  }
};


btnLogin.addEventListener('click',loginUser);
```

Comment: Are you using a button of type submit ?

Comment: jateen, I changed it from button to submit and now it is working fine. What might be the reason?